# Can't get client IPs in mod_status from mod_remoteip

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have Nginx setup as a reverse proxy and it's passing IPs to Apache.
For some reason mod_status wont recognise client IPs and instead shows my website IP as a client IP.

Here is my old Apache 2.2 `mod_rpaf` configuraton:

```
RPAFenable On
RPAFproxy_ips 127.0.0.1 website IP server IP
RPAFsethostname On 
RPAFheader X-Forwarded-For
```

New Apache 2.4 `mod_remoteip` configuration:

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 127.0.0.1 website IP server IP
```

Is it about wrong `mod_realip` configuration or is it that Apache 2.4 isn't supposed to work like this?

Also logs weren't working correctly, but were fixed by changing the format from %h to %a.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I cannot get the real IP as well when looking into the mod_status page.

Answer (score 1):

Additional info:
Nginx proxy configuration
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://www.domain.com:8080;
    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    }

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrestled with something similar all morning. There is a known bug in mod_rpaf: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libapache2-mod-rpaf/+bug/930540

Here is what worked for me. In /etc/apache2/mods-available/rpaf.conf simply replace:

```
<IfModule mod_rpaf.c>
```

with:

```
<IfModule mod_rpaf-2.0.c>
```

(Credit: https://serverfault.com/questions/393207/mod-rpaf-problems-with-nginx-front-apache-back-end-after-ubuntu-upgrade)